# Recovery HD partition resized (now 300GB)

Tags: disk-utility, partition

I recently deleted my bootcamp partition that was 300GB and then tried to resize my Macintosh HD partition to my full 500GB hard drive, but after I tried to do this, instead my Recovery HD took the 300GB from bootcamp so now I am stuck with this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            199.2 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             300.6 GB   disk0s3
```

Is there any way I can resize the partitions so that I have one Macintosh HD partition at about 500GB and the Recovery HD the normal size? (About 650MB). I have tried using the following command in terminal :

```
diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s3 650M
```

but I get the following message when I try to do that:

```
Unable to resize because file system volume format does not support resizing
```

Any Ideas? I have 300GB just sitting idle because of this currently. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I found this site http://osxdaily.com/2011/06/30/deleting-the-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-recovery-hd-partition/

Which explains that you erase the Recovery HD with this command "diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ Blank /dev/disk0s4"

And merge it with this command "diskutil mergePartitions HFS+ Lion disk0s3 disk0s4"

Before erasing the Recovery HD
[image: Before erasing volume]

After merging it to my macOS partition, which i used Disk Utility to do that.
[image: After erasing volume]

Comment: Please  adjust the commands to the OP's environment or express them in more general terms: there is neither a disk0s4 nor a Lion partition on Jacob's disk0! Additionally: the `diskutil mergePartitions ...` command doesn't require to reformat the absorbed partitions!